# How does one initialize large arrays in Mathematica with a structured format?

Tags: matrix, expression-construction

I want to create a 10 by 10 matrix that increases by 1 every unit across like:

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 11.....
```

Is there a function that does this without having 10 "{....}" with 10 entries in each one and manually adding them? I can't find it on the Mathematica website under matrix initialization.

Comment: Welcome! `Table` or `Partition` should be useful here.

Comment: or you can use Partition[Range[10*10], 10] ;-) There are a lot of ways...

Comment: Array[#2 + (#1 - 1)*10 &, {10, 10}]

Comment: To play devils advocate if its a large matrix you may want to hold off initialising it at all/until the last moment.  ie there might be more efficient ways of meeting your needs other than a initialised matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of options:

```
Range[100] ~Partition~ 10

Array[10 # + #2 - 10 &, {10, 10}]
```

Just for fun, assuming no collisions:

```
ArrayComponents @ RandomReal[1, {10, 10}]
```

A rather inefficient use of `SparseArray`:

```
SparseArray[{i_, j_} :> 10 (i - 1) + j, {10, 10}] // Normal
```

And a nice one from [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/) in the comments:

```
NestList[# + 10 &, Range[10], 9]
```

Comment: Infix inoculation 

Comment: Three more: `Outer[10 #1 + #2 &, Range[10] - 1, Range[10]]`, `NestList[# + 10 &, Range[10], 9]`, and `Array[10 # + #2 &, {10, 10}, {0, 1}]`.

Comment: And there was I, just one click from voting to close...

Comment: @Yves Don't let my answer deter you.